# Copy excel file from Sharepoint to Azure DLS with Logic app and keeping excel formatting

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory

I use a Azure Logic app to copy excel files from a Sharepoint folder into a Datalake storage account. From here I use ADF to copy the data into an SQL DB.

Some values in the excel files have formatting on them, so for example a cell is calculated with a formula which returns 4,18128342349 but with formatting in excel the cell looks like 4.2x.

When I use my logic app the "underlying" value is copied, and not the formatted data. I.e. in the DLS the cell contains 4,18128342349. Is there any way to not take the actual value of the cell but instead take the formatted value?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

With ADF Copy Data Activity I've tried to move the xlsx file from DLS to SQL DB and the underlying values is what is copied. This is the case even if add a step where I convert the xslx files to csv before I move them to the SQL DB.

The logic app that moves the files from sharepoint to DLS:
[image: The logic app that moves the files from sharepoint to DLS]

EDIT 2:
The problem is not that the formatting is removed when I transfer the file and open it in excel. The problem occurs when I load the data into an SQL DB:

1. Input file:

[image: Input file]

1. Logic app as above
2. ADF Copy Data Activity with the DLS as Source and an SQL DB as SINK.
3. Output in the SQL DB:

[image: Output in the SQL DB]

Comment: Would be easier to help if you gave us some insights into what the flow looks like. Also, are you confusing your issue with the copy step? Is t this just about the values and the formatting?

Comment: I've added some clarification to the issue and also what steps I do, hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: This is an ADF topic, it has nothing to do with LogicApps.  All LogicApps is doing is moving the file from one location to another.  I would suggest that ADF is simply getting the value, not the text of the field, this is pretty standard behaviour for any system like this.  If you want ADF to do what you want, you may have to be a bit smarter and use an alternative method for retrieving the values, like MS Graph or adding `text()` formulas to cells to format it via that method.

Answer (score 0):

I have below value and formatted it like below:

[image]

Then used below **`design`** in Logic apps like below:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

After downloading, you can see its in formatted form:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works when you download the file and open it in excel. The problem occurs when I load the data into an SQL DB, then the formatting is removed. I updated my post with clarification and the steps I use.


EDIT: Also, what does the "Infer content type" setting do in the Get file content in you logic app? I saw that mine was set to Yes, and your no. I don't think I changed that when I set up the app.

Comment: Its the content type of file. Formatted setting will only be for excel sheet and not for the actual data when loading it.