# [Excel]Keep cell formatting as text in new cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some custom formatting in some cells in my sheet. I.e a cell is calculated with a formula which returns 4,18128342349 but with formatting in excel the cell looks like 4.2x.

Is there any way to write a formula so that I get the formatted cell is stored as text. So I want the actual value of the new cell to be "4.2x".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apparently you are hiding some requirements from your question, as you were "kind enough" to explain as a comment on my answer. If you cannot provide the complete requirements, this question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Pick the number format of your cell (which I expect should be close to or exactly `#.#"x"`) and use it in conjunction with the `TEXT` function. Note that you need to double the double-quotes in order to escape them.

```
=TEXT(A1, "#.#""x""")
```

Of course, there is not need to store your result as a number in your cell. You can directly apply `TEXT` in that fashion:

```
=TEXT(<current formula generating your result>, "#.#""x""")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I'm looking for is more of a generic solution, so for the cases that I won't know the formatting beforehand or that the formatting can be different for different cells in the same column.

Comment: Nothing you are writing here regarding a "more generic solution" is written in your question. Quite the opposite: you are writing that you have a number format, never mentionned another, and you want the formula value to become text. How do you expect people to guess what is in your head? Not to mention [your other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77794403/copy-excel-file-from-sharepoint-to-azure-dls-with-logic-app-and-keeping-excel-fo) only shows 1 cell which happens to contain that 1 value you have included here. Safe for anyone to assume that is your only case to cover.

Comment: Maybe you need the option `Set precision as displayed` = "Permanently changes stored values in cells from full precision (15 digits) to whatever format is displayed, including decimal places." However this option does not convert numeric result into text but works for different format options as long as the number of decimal places is defined.

Comment: I don't see how any requirement described with "*I won't know the formatting beforehand*" can be fulfilled. IMO, an explanation about that part is mandatory.